# Saving the result to file - JAVA

Tags: java, dijkstra, output

I have a very stupid problem... I cannot get know how to save the results in output file that second array is save in a lower line.

This is how it saves:

dist[0 10 13 10 6 18 ] pred[-15 2 5 1 4 ]

I want it to save like this:

```
dist[0 10 13 10 6 18 ]
pred[-15 2 5 1 4 ]
```

CODE:

```
try{
outputFile = new File("Out0304.txt");
out = new FileWriter(outputFile);
out.write("\n" + "dist[");
out.write("\n");

for (Top way : tops){
    out.write(way.shortest_path + " ");
}

out.write("]\n");
out.write("\n");
out.write("\n" + "pred[");

for (Top ww : tops){
    if (ww.previous != null) {
        out.write(ww.previous.number + " ");
    }
            else{
        out.write("-1");
    }
}
out.write("] \n ");
out.close();
} 

 catch (IOException e){
System.out.println("Blad: " + e.toString());
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use the following to write to file:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("fileName"),true);
pw.println("[");
for(int i=0;i<pred.length;i++)
{
pw.println(pred[i]+" ");
}
pw.println("]");
pw.close();
```

Comment: What `File` are you writing to, again?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows you need `"\r\n"` for new line